# IntelliJ module settings change when the build.gradle is updated

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, module, dependencies, cucumber-jvm

So i have a multi-module project in IntelliJ. I added new modules to the project with dependencies on the existing modules. Using Cucumber as framework and Gradle as the dependency management tool. Every module has a build.gradle.

Example :

> automation-rest  --> dependent on 'core' module
>
> (NEW MODULE CREATED) automation-client . --> dependent on 'rest' and 'core'

Whenever i update the `build.gradle` in `automation-client` module, the `Source` and `Test Resources` setting in the Module Dependencies are changed automatically.

Why does it do that everytime? Is it related to the folders that I am setting as my `Source` and `test resource`?

Answer (score 0):

This is an intended behavior. To disable it, please go to File | Settings | Build,Execution,Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle, then check "Offline work". Click the "OK" button.Then Rebuild the Project.